# Open New Tab with JQuery in a way that Chrome does not block

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, tabs, popup, block

I need a code to open a new window or tab.

I have searched a lot, I found several but all are blocked by the Pop Ups Blocker of Chorme.

Is there any way to automatically open a link in another tab or window but that Chrome does not block?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this (javascript), where the `url` var is the url you wish to open:

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

Note: this assumes that you're not writing anything new to the window and have a URL to open..

This turns over default functionality to the browser for what to show (window or tab) and suggests to use `target='_blank'` and then focuses on that new window/tab.. I've yet to see this blocked as a pop-up, but honestly it really is a client side issue - a lot of browsers will block ANY tabs opened with javascript as it typically is just considered annoying.